# NoMethodError - undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x007fdd28be0430>:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have an array of collections from my model that is coming from Active Record .

```
@ad_groups = AdGroup.where(is_template: false).paginate(:page =>  params[:page]).order(:id).reverse
```

Then in my model I have

```
self.per_page = 25
WillPaginate.per_page = 25
```

in my view for index

```
=   will_paginate @ad_groups
```

As well as required the will_paginate/array. I saw that someone used this code in the initializers

```
require 'will_paginate/collection'

class Array
  # Paginates a static array (extracting a subset of it). The result is a
  # WillPaginate::Collection instance, which is an array with a few more
  # properties about its paginated state.
  #
  # Parameters:
  # * <tt>:page</tt> - current page, defaults to 1
  # * <tt>:per_page</tt> - limit of items per page, defaults to 30
  # * <tt>:total_entries</tt> - total number of items in the array, defaults to
  #   <tt>array.length</tt> (obviously)
  #
  # Example:
  #   arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
  #   paged = arr.paginate(:per_page => 2)      #->  ['a', 'b']
  #   paged.total_entries                       #->  5
  #   arr.paginate(:page => 2, :per_page => 2)  #->  ['c', 'd']
  #   arr.paginate(:page => 3, :per_page => 2)  #->  ['e']
  #
  # This method was originally {suggested by Desi
  # McAdam}[http://www.desimcadam.com/archives/8] and later proved to be the
  # most useful method of will_paginate library.
  def paginate(options = {})
    page     = options[:page] || 1
    per_page = options[:per_page] || WillPaginate.per_page
    total    = options[:total_entries] || self.length

    WillPaginate::Collection.create(page, per_page, total) do |pager|
      pager.replace self[pager.offset, pager.per_page].to_a
    end
  end
end
```

Didn't work. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have `.reverse` at the end of your query. This method would return an array of models, not `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Just add ordering you need to your `.order()` method:

```
@ad_groups = AdGroup.where(is_template: false)
                 .paginate(:page =>  params[:page]).order('id DESC')
#                                                HERE ======= |
```